# Drawing issue when using RDP

Tags: java, eclipse, swt

I develop a stock market trading software based on the Eclipse RCP framework that plots historical charts.  When it's used remotely, via Windows mstsc, the charts are not drawn correctly.

I managed to create a fairly simple example that reproduces the problem.  Here's what it does.  It creates two threads, each of which draws an image with a certain number of squares.  The first image has pink squares and the second image has alternating green and red squares.  Each thread has its own Display, Image, GC and Color objects.  Before drawing each square, the code randomly sets the antialias property on and off.

When I run this code locally it produces the expected images.

[image: Pink squares]  .  [image: Alternating squares]

But when I access a machine using Windows mstsc utility and run this code, the images produced are wrong.  The all-pink one misses some squares.  The alternating one misses some squares and has some with the wrong color.

[image: Pink squares]  .  [image: Alternating squares]

I discovered that if I don't change the antialias setting, the images are drawn correctly.

Does anyone have any clue of what's happening?  Does my code have any mistakes?

The example code follows.  It should be used in an existing RCP project.

These two lines can be placed on the `execute` method of an `Action`, or the `widgedSelected` method of a `SelectionListener`.

```
new Thread( new MyRunnable( "RUN_A", true ), "A" ).start(); //$NON-NLS-1$ //$NON-NLS-2$
new Thread( new MyRunnable( "RUN_B", false ), "B" ).start(); //$NON-NLS-1$ //$NON-NLS-2$
```

This class can be used as an inner class within the same file where the two lines above where used.

```
private static class MyRunnable implements Runnable {

        private String name;
        private boolean singleColor;

        public MyRunnable( String name, boolean singleColor ) {
            this.name = name;
            this.singleColor = singleColor;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Color colorA = null;
            Color colorB = null;

            if ( singleColor ) {
                colorA = new Color( Display.findDisplay( Thread.currentThread() ), 255, 0, 128 );
            } else {
                colorA = new Color( Display.findDisplay( Thread.currentThread() ), 193, 98, 107 );
                colorB = new Color( Display.findDisplay( Thread.currentThread() ), 146, 190, 137 );
            }

            Display display = new Display();
            Image image = new Image( display, 1000, 1000 );
            GC gc = new GC( image );

            int items = 20;

            for ( int i = 0; i < items; i++ ) {
                for ( int j = 0; j < items; j++ ) {
                    int x = i * ( 1000 / items ) + ( 1000 / items / 4 );
                    int y = j * ( 1000 / items ) + ( 1000 / items / 4 );

                    gc.setAntialias( (int) ( Math.random() * 2 ) );

                    Color bg;

                    if ( singleColor ) {
                        bg = colorA;
                    } else {
                        if ( ( i + j ) % 2 == 1 ) {
                            bg = colorA;
                        } else {
                            bg = colorB;
                        }
                    }

                    gc.setBackground( bg );
                    gc.fillRectangle( x, y, 1000 / items / 2, 1000 / items / 2 );
                }
            }

            ImageLoader imageLoader = new ImageLoader();
            imageLoader.data = new ImageData[] { image.getImageData() };
            imageLoader.save( "C:\\img\\" + name + ".png", SWT.IMAGE_PNG ); //$NON-NLS-1$ //$NON-NLS-2$

            gc.dispose();
            image.dispose();
            display.dispose();

            colorA.dispose();

            if ( colorB != null ) {
                colorB.dispose();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Note: Using multiple `Display` objects is very unusual. Some platforms (macOS for example) don't support this at all.

Comment: Yeah, I know.  But in our case it's necessary and proved to be useful.

Comment: I don't see that the new display is necessary. Just changing your class to use `Display.getDefault()` (and not disposing it) works fine for me.

Comment: As our software draws lots and lots of Images, we use two Displays to draw those images on a different thread without interfering on the main UI thread.  If there's a better way to do that, we'd love to see an explanation.  ;)

Comment: You aren't actually using the displays you create, all your drawing is on the `Image` which does not make use of the display (yes I know you have to pass one to the constructor but the drawing operations don't reference it). As I said your threads work fine just using `Display.getDefault()` (and don't work at all on my Mac using your original code).

Comment: I get your point, but if we use `Display.getDefault()` on our drawing thread, we get _Invalid thread access_ errors.